# Enable tuareg mode in the emacs shell

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

In emacs I have got the tuareg mode enabled in the top and the shell in the bottom without color syntax. How can I have color syntax in the shell?

In order to get here, I installed camllight using this script http://judicael.courant.free.fr/2015/02/20/installationcaml.html
then, I installed melpa

```
M-x list-packages
```

to search and to install tuareg. And finally, I edited .emacs with (add to list 'load-path "home/pi/.emacs.d/lisp") where lisp is a directory which contain tuareg.el, camldebug.el, tuareg-site-file-el

emacs window:

[image: emacs window]

Comment: I'm not sure you should be expect to be able to.

Comment: The goal I would like to achieve is to have the same configuration as him vimeo.com/50544476

Answer (score 0):

The mode that you're [looking for](https://vimeo.com/50544476) is not the one that comes with Tuareg. The guy in the video is using the inferior-ocaml mode that is a part of an old [caml-mode](https://github.com/ocaml/caml-mode) that used to be distributed with the OCaml compiler. Unless you really want the exact setup as in the video, I would suggest you use a more modern Tuareg mode together with the OCaml Merlin. Otherwise, you should remove Tuareg and install `caml-mode` using `M-x package-install <RET> caml-mode <RET>` (see also the documentation on the Github page of the project for more details).